# How to buy a car without SSN for someone on a student/travelers visa

Tags: students, car, usa

I'm currently in the United Stated on a travelers Visa but am in the process of converting it to a Student Visa. I currently use public transportation but in San Diego it's not very convenient. My questions are:

- How to get a Driver's License without a SSN?
- How to purchase a car without a SSN?

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: You just can't. No one would be willing to insure your car. But the moment you get your student visa there is a stem program where you can apply for a SSN.

Answer (score 3):

In California you can apply for a driver's license without a SSN [if you can prove legal presence (e.g. an F visa) but are ineligible for a SSN](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffdl08). Once you become eligible for a SSN you must obtain one and provide it to the DMV when you renew your license (which you will do frequently since California licenses for non-immigrants expire when their current legal presence does).

Once you have a license I don't believe a SSN is required to buy and register a car if you pay cash for it; you certainly won't get a loan without a SSN or ITIN since one of these is needed for a credit check. You'll need to make sure you can insure the car without a SSN, but I suspect this may not be a big problem since I don't recall having to provide mine to my own insurer.

Comment: While I am not promoting the company, this [website](https://www.800loanmart.com/blog/solutions-for-loans-without-a-social-security-number) says *To borrow money with a car title loan, let's start with what you don't need. First, you do not need a Social Security Number. Second, you don't need a bank account. Finally, it is not necessary that you have good credit.* Please provide evidence that a car loan requires a SSN.

Comment: @StrongBad, I think a loan requires some identifier for credit reporting and I'm pretty sure he won't be able to get an ITIN in a hurry either since I understand new applications for those need to accompany a tax return that he won't have any immediate need to file. That could be wrong, though, I've not been in the position.